# Syntax error while running webpack encore

Tags: webpack, webpack-encore

Get error while running webpack encore using below command

> ./node_module/.bin/encore dev

Please help. Thanks in advance :) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update node version from v6 to v8 resolve my issue